# How did Dragon Ball “break the internet”?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Having a discussion with some people who are saying Gokus MUI transformation and DBS are the best in all of anime because it broke the internet. What does this even mean? Did manga sales reach some sort of high or was there a huge amount of viewers or something?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat a hyperbole but not far from the truth.
Due to simulcast nature of streaming sites like Crunchyroll, sometimes, a surge in views can break a streaming service.

Here are just two news reports I found in [2018](https://comicbook.com/anime/news/dragon-ball-super-goku-vs-jiren-crunchyroll-delay/) and [2017](https://aminoapps.com/c/dragonballz/page/blog/fun-fact-goku-vs-jiren-scored-the-worst-ratings-in-dbs-history/1JLT_6ud6LzGZd7m1z6N1BD6gVDQVXB) at a cursory search. Both refer to the Dragon Ball Super's hour-long special, although it may have happened elsewhere.